# Convert PHP class to a native class

Tags: php, pear

Is there a way to embed a group of PHP classes into PHP, so that I can call them natively without including the classes as files every time? I need this to be locally used or on a private server.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem would it solve for you?

Comment: @Tim Its good if you change a function file to a new version and want to make sure every file is using the new version

Comment: i want to cut the time these files are processed in, and use them a native parts of PHP, on my private server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For laziness you could use the php.ini setting:

```
 auto_prepend_file = /usr/share/php/allmypredefinedclasses.php
```

The [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/auto_prepend_file) is included before any script is run. It sounds like that is what you want. It could very well define classes or functions, or just be an autoloader. But you should avoid to use it for overly project-specific functionality - as it will impact *all* PHP scripts.

(I'm personally using it to hobble on some PHP6 functionality..)

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't work for my case the same way i want it

Comment: Ok. Now it seems you would want to turn your php classes into native PHP extensions. But that's probably too much effort in any case. (The script processing time is drastically reduced by using a bytecode cache, btw.)

Comment: YEB, NATIVE PHP EXTENSIONS , how can i do this

Comment: That's awfully difficult. I doubt you really want to do this. Native PHP extensions must be written in C, not in PHP. http://talks.php.net/show/extending-php-apachecon2003 or http://www.php.net/~wez/extending-php.pdf and http://conf.phpquebec.com/slides/2009/PHP_Extension_Writing-phpquebec_2009.pdf - I can't even find a good introduction.

Comment: WOW, that sucks & impossible for me :)!, Thanks

Comment: what a bout PEAR, is there a way to use it locally, without publishing the package ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. PEAR classes are ordinary PHP scripts, you can usually install them manually without the package system thingy.

Comment: Oh, so they also to be processed just as normal included files !, that ends it, so no way ... Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 6):

You may want to use [__autoload()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) if i understand you correctly.

Note from @[KingCrunch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421223/kingcrunch):

> The __autoload() function should not
>   be used anymore, because if you use
>   other libraries, that define an
>   spl-loader, the function is never call
>   since then

So it'd be better if you stick with [SPL Autoload functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Comment: I would also recommend using the [SPL Autoload functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Comment: The `__autoload()` function should not be used anymore, because if you use other libraries, that define an spl-loader, the function is never call since then.

Comment: But here i still will need to call the classes as files & that's exactly i don't wanna do !

Comment: @Dewan159 Yes, you're right. But you don't need to include them. And that was the original problem, or not?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the content of each file without `<?php` and `?>` into a file `classes.inc.php` and just include this file.

[edit]
I don't think that you need so much performance, because PHP is already fast. But if you are really including every class file you need into every file, which sometimes just needs one of the classes, than it's a bad idea.

Why don't you split your classes into modules:

eg: DatabaseModule `database.module.php` contains the classes `connection`, `queries`, `results`

Than put all your classes in groups like this and move them into a directory `modules/`

Than you can use a custom function, here a simple example:

```
<?php
function loadModule($name) {
    $file_path = './modules/' . $name . '.module.php';
    require_once $file_path;
}
?>
```

Now you can just add all the modules you need in every file with the `loadModule` function.

I hope that helped you.

Comment: I wanna cut the times this classes are revised by php, and just use them as native parts of the language

Comment: Why don't you use a tool, which precompiles the PHP on the Server to C Code, which makes it very fast. Eventually [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090124/convert-php-to-c-code) can help you.

Comment: leo, i am already using this style, but as i told you, i wanna cut all of that and call any class i want any time in any file with out including the classes files or use additional function, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

just add the path to php.ini and they will always be available on that server

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an MVC pattern, where for example, the index.php page is called on every request, then __autoload would be a good solution. Failing that you could use 'auto_prepend_file' as previously suggested.

Hope that helps.